# uninitialized constant hit on nested model when running test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following class

```
class Producttag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  belongs_to :variant, optional: true
```

is a child of its parent

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :productags, dependent: :destroy
```

whom itself is in a chain of two other parents.  Each class calls `dependent: :destroy` on its children.

When running tests on a destroy action, each class encounters the same error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Product::Productag
```

or on the variant class

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Variant::Productag
```

all other parnet child relations dependencies get destroyed, but not this latter one.  The only difference that is apparent is the `optional: true` placed on the relationship.  This is an assumption regarding the error in the destroy action, but hard to comprehend.

If this is the motive, why?  or what is missing then to allow destruction of the 'optional' child
records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is `Producttag` but your relation is `has_many :productags, dependent: :destroy`.

You are missing a "t" in product**t**ag and this is causing rails to look for a "class_name" `Productag`

That being said `ProductTag` and `product_tag` would have made this a lot more obvious